# c# Prioritizing extension methods (only)

Tags: c#

Let me start with the code... Please note this is not a question about overriding instance methods - this deals purely with extension methods. This code is being used in the Unity3D game engine, version 5.3.x

```
public static class ExtentionMethods {

    public static string ToJson<T>(this List<T> list) {
        string s = "[";
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
            if (i > 0)
                s += ",";
            s += list[i].ToJson();
        }
        return s + "]";
    }

    public static string ToJson(this object o) {
        if (o == null)
            return "null";
        return o.ToString();
    }

    public static string ToJson(this string value){
        return "\"" + value + "\"";
    }
}
```

and

```
public List<string> list = new List<string>();
void Start () {
    list.Add ("dog0");
    list.Add ("dog1");
    list.Add ("dog2");
    Debug.Log (list.ToJson());  

    string s = "elephants";
    Debug.Log (s.ToJson());  
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
[dog0,dog1,dog2]
"elephants"
```

It seems that a string calling the ToJson() function may use either the object or the string type. Is there any way to make it only use the string version of the method?

Comment: I wonder if an off-the-shelf JSON serialization library might not be a better idea (unless you've already identified a code hot-spot through measurement with a performance-profiler). JSON serialization is a solved problem.

Comment: He would at least use string builder if he cared about performance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overload resolution, extension methods and genericity in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878866/overload-resolution-extension-methods-and-genericity-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

At this point:

```
s += list[i].ToJson();
```

...all the compiler knows is that `list[i]` is an object, so that's the extension method you get. You'd have to look at the type of `list[i]` and call the string overload if it's a string, e.g.,

```
object o = list[i];
string s = o as string;
if (s != null)
{
    s += s.ToJson();
}
else
{
    s += o.ToJson();
}
```

Extension methods are nice syntactic sugar, but don't expect too much in the way of generic magic. :-)

Comment: The `unity3d` tag doesn't really apply here; this is a pure `C#` question, methinks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way without checking type and calling matching type's ToJson method with a cast. (Petter already gave an answer about this)

If I was facing similar problem, I would add another extension for string lists:

```
public static string ToJson(this List<string> list) {
   // ... Body is the same with other ToJson<T>(List<T>)
}
```

This way string lists get bind to this method during compile. Since compiler knows that values are string, inner ToJson method will be bind correctly with string one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check what type of T is:

```
s += typeof(T)==typeof(string) ? list[i].ToString().ToJson() : list[i].ToJson();
```